# Can not import class from custom django package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I am writing a custom Django module but I seem to have something wrong.  I cannot import a class that lives in a certain file. I get the error

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'admins': Cannot resolve 'myPackage.handlers.MyHandlerClass': No module named handlers
```

This is the directory structure.  I believe I can import views and models with no problem.

```
myPackage
├── CHANGELOG.rst
├── myPackage
│   ├── handlers .py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── myPackage.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

Comment: Is the space in `handlers .py` a typo?  If not, that could be your problem.  How are you running the code?  I don't see a `manage.py`, so I assume you're importing from another package.  Is `myPackage` in your `sys.path`?

Comment: DAMN!!! There was a space in the file name thanks!

Comment: @aquavitae you can add your comment as an answer since it seems you found the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space in the filename of `handlers .py`, so python can't find a module names `handlers`.  Obviously the easiest fix is to correct the filename, but for anyone actually wanting a space in the filename, `import name with spaces` is a syntax error, so the only way to import such a name is using `__import__`.  But this is really a very bad idea.